# How can I configure PHP to ignore error_reporting() at runtime?

Tags: php

I am running an application which is riddled with error_reporting calls, but I'm running PHP 5.5 which has a lot of depreciated warnings. I have configured my php.ini file correctly like this.

```
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

But all of the error_reporting() calls override it. Is there any way I configire to ignore runtime calls to error_reporting()?

Changing all the error_reporting() calls is a real hassle, especially as the application will need to be regularly updated and I want to avoid running a post install hack script.

I don't want to mention the name of the app, it's VBulletin 5.

Comment: "I don't want to mention the name of the app, it's VBulletin 5." Yep. If there is an `error_reporting()` call in an application, this is a hint for bad PHP developers. `error_reporting` should ony be set via the server configuration (i.e. `php.ini`).

Comment: `str_replace('error_reporting', '', $code);` ;-)

Comment: It would be nice if you could "force" redefine a function. like you can do in JavaScript. Oh well.

Comment: In VBullentin there are a lot of calls to chanage to error reporting. And I meant A LOT. On one of my dev machines I'm running a higher version of PHP than is supported. VBullentin is proprietary code so helping to improve the code is not an option especially when we will be rolling out updates as they are released. If you read the  original post, I think I make myself quite clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an ini-setting `disable_functions`, which you could use to disable the `error_reporting()` function. That way the application can not set the error reporting level via this function.

```
disable_functions = error_reporting
```

> Only internal functions can be disabled using this directive. User-defined functions are unaffected. 
>   This directive must be set in php.ini For example, you cannot set this in httpd.conf.

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions

Comment: Combating evil with *extreme* evil. I like it! +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

If you have control over the webserver configuration you can use `php_admin_value` to set `error_reporting` to a value that cannot be overriden.

According to [the documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php) this cannot be used in a .htaccess file, so you will have to use it on the whole server ... maybe a little too much.

Another possibility would be to use [disable_functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.disable-functions) to disable error_reporting. Downside would be that you will get a warning every time it is used, but you can get around that:

You can add a section to your php.ini that only affects the specified script:

```
[PATH=<path>]
error_reporting = 0
disable_functions = "error_reporting"
```

Comment: Hahah. Yeah warnings, but this is the sort of thing I was thinking of. Ta